# Loop thru all specific form field

Tags: forms

i am working on a recipe form where there are many fields asking for recipe ingredients.
for example my code is some thing like this

```
            <legend><span>Recipe Ingredients</span></legend>
                <label for="recipe_ing" title="Ingredients Name" class="required">Ingredient:<span>*</span></label>
                <input name="recipe_ingr" id="recipe_ingr"  size="10" />    &nbsp;  
                Quantity: <input id="recipe_qty" name="recipe_qty" size="5" />  &nbsp; 
                unit: <input id="recipe_unit" name="recipe_unit" size="5" />    &nbsp;
                Notes: <input type="text" id="recipe_notes" name="recipe_notes" size="15" />&nbsp; <br /><br />


                <label for="recipe_ing" title="Ingredients Name" class="required">Ingredient2:<span>*</span></label>
                <input name="recipe_ingr2" id="recipe_ingr"  size="10" />   &nbsp;  
                Quantity: <input id="recipe_qty" name="recipe_qty2" size="5" /> &nbsp; 
                unit: <input id="recipe_unit" name="recipe_unit2" size="5" />   &nbsp;
                Notes: <input type="text" id="recipe_notes" name="recipe_notes2" size="15" />&nbsp; <br /><br />
```

its goes up to 15 ingredients, quantity, units and notes

the form data is processed and controlled by formcheck.php

now the problem or my question is, what is the possible option/function in formcheck.php so that instead of defining 15 time if(isset($_POST[])) i run a loop thru and it gets all relevant data of ingredients, quantity, units and notes

i hope i make myself clear

Answer (score 0):

What if you leave out the number in your different form fields ?
So make 15 "recipe_ingr" fields. In perl, you get 1 variable with all the values in it.

or make a for loop from 1 to 15 ?

Comment: i can make any required changes, i can make them all recipe_ingr. since i dont know very much of php, what would be the proper loop function to cycle thru all values?

Comment: I don't know PHP (either), but maybe this can help you:
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3699